# Function 'concat' (in JavaScript) is not working for associative arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

I have a problem concatenating two associative arrays in JavaScript. Below is the sample code:

```
var firstArray =  new Array();
firstArray.c1 = "sam";
firstArray.c2 = "kam";
var secArray =  new Array();
secArray.c3 = "sam";
secArray.c4 = "kam";
var res = firstArray.concat(secArray);
```

Is this a known limitation?

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: wow.... may i know why the heck i am downvoted........ asking question is wrong here..?? pls show ur face ur friend.......

Comment: I didn't vote you down, but I guess it would be something to do with the fact that you don't really explain the problem you are seeing

Comment: brother i gave all the info i got... (concatenating two associative arrays ).. isnt that enough... ppl ask questions because they dont know.... right..

Comment: @Ramesh: have you read the http://stackoverflow.com/faq?

Comment: @Ramesh: you didn't show what the result was. You didn't show what result you hoped to achieve.

Comment: Ramesh, this kind of questions needs: a) What you tried, b) What you expected to happen and c) What actaully happened. You didn't supply b) and c)

Comment: Sometimes i get voted down, for no apparent reason at all, just because the question/answer(mainly) don't fit in some folks brains..

I guess it is the price for a great democratic Q/A's site

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are not using `Array` functionality - just `Object` functionality. In JavaScript, `Object` is an associative array - you use `Array` for arrays indexed by integers. If you did

```
var firstArray =  new Array();
firstArray.push("sam");  
firstArray.push("kam");
var secArray =  new Array();
secArray.push("sam");    
secArray.push("kam");
var res = firstArray.concat(secArray);
```

then `concat` would work as expected.

If you actually want to merge associative arrays, do:

```
for (var attr in src_array) { dest_array[attr] = src_array[attr]; }
```

This will of course overwrite existing keys in `dest_array` which have counterparts in `src_array`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var firstArray = new Array("sam", "kam");
var secArray = new Array("sam", "kam");
var res = firstArray.concat(secArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays; it has object hashes. You're creating an array and assigning values to some of its properties, not in the array itself.

Your concat will not work because the values are object properties.  To do a concat the way you have it, you'll need to combine the two objects. [YUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_UI_Library), jQuery, and the other JavaScript frameworks provide helpful methods to do just that.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, those aren't associative arrays at all: they are arrays of zero length, with additional named properties. Assigning those properties works because arrays are also objects in JavaScript; but that doesn't make them an associative array. It's better to look at them as hashes.

Array methods such as `concat` will only work with the numerically-indexed elements of arrays, not with the properties of objects - even if those objects happen to be arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in JavaScript have only numerical keys. Only objects can have non numerical properties. So try this instead:

```
var firstArray = {};
firstArray.c1 = "sam";
firstArray.c2 = "kam";
var secArray =  {};
secArray.c3 = "sam";  
secArray.c4 = "kam";

for (var prop in secArray) {
    if (secArray.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        firstArray[prop] = secArray[prop];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the redundancy? You're looping over the properties in the second array and then calling "hasOwnProperty" on the second array with the value from the first loop.  Did you mean to test "hasOwnProperty" on the first array?